# PowerMockito: mocking private method and get a value without accessing it

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, powermock

I'm writing java unit test for a legacy code and I'm new to this area as well. I have to test following scenario (write unit test case for the `testableMethod()`). So, **without executing** code inside the `getMode()` method, I want to get a value for the `mode` variable.

```
Class A{

 public boolean testableMethod()
 {
   //code
   ......
   int mode = getMode();
   ......
   //do something with mode
   return X;
 }

 private int getMode()
 {
   return ComplexCalls(ComplexMethodCalls(), more());
 }

}
```

I've tried to do it using PowerMockito without getting success. It is possible to mock these kind of scenario with PowerMockito?.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can with a [`PowerMockito`](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13#Partial_Mocking) spy:

```
public class A {
    public boolean testableMethod() {
        return getMode() == 1;
    }

    private int getMode() {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

---

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.doReturn;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.spy;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(A.class)
public class ATest {
    @Test
    public void testableMethod_should_do_this() throws Exception {
        A a = spy(new A());

        doReturn(1).when(a, "getMode");

        assertTrue(a.testableMethod());
    }
}
```

See all this [full example of partial mocking of a private method](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13#A_full_example_of_partial_mocking_of_a_private_method)

Comment: I have tried this scenario. I debug the execution using eclipse IDE. In this case, debug pointer goes into the getMode() method which has very complex code to test and make errors.

Comment: if i want to pass few values then?

Comment: @Inquisitive could you elaborate your question ?

Comment: what if the method with derived type argument like this, private int getMode(Person p, String value) {
        return 5;
    }
do i need to mock person class or simply doReturn(1).when(a, "getMode", Person.class, anyString()); is enough? @gontard